# Change HTML with variables in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the dict latest_status:

```
{'What': 10, "Study'": 10, 'all': 10, 'to': 10, "facebook'": 10, 'has': 10, 'worth': 20, 'hurting': 10 }
```

I am trying to make a text cloud by doing something like this in my template:

```
{% for word,count in latest_status.items %}
<style="font-size:{{ count }}px"> {{ word }}</style> 
{% endfor %}
```

I am trying to manipulate the font size with the count from the dict but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working"? What does the output source look like, and what should it look like?

Comment: A row of words with different sizes based on the font-size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<style>` tag is used to introduce a block (or external resource) containing style definitions. You'll want to encapsulate your text in a presentation tag of some sort--for example:

```
{% for word,count in latest_status.items %}
<p style="font-size:{{ count }}px;"> {{ word }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sweet that works but is there anyway I can just return them inline? I'm not very good with html/css. Right now, every word is a new line.

Comment: Use `span` instead of `p`. Although seriously, if you're doing web development you need to know enough HTML/CSS to know the difference between block and inline elements.

Comment: @daniel Yeah, I'm kinda slowly working through the list. I have the bare minimum basics in HTML/CSS but I'm getting there! :)